# what is the wrong of my query?

Tags: mysql

here is my tables

```
 create table guest (

             guest_id           int auto_increment primary key unique not null,
             guest_lname        varchar(50) not null,
             guest_fname        varchar(50) not null,

             guest_email        varchar(100) not null,
             guest_password     varchar(50) not null,
             guest_address      varchar(20) not null,
             guest_op_adres     varchar(200),
             guest_gender       int(1) not null,
             guest_mobile_no    varchar(15) not null
            );

  create table room_rate_default (
     defroom_rateID      int auto_increment not null primary key,
     room_typeID int not null,
     defseason_type  varchar(50) not null,
     defmonRate      double not null,
     deftuesRate double not null,
     defwedRate      double not null,
     defthuRate      double not null,
     deffriRate      double not null,
     defsatRate      double not null,
     defsunRate      double not null,
     foreign key(room_typeID)references room_type(room_typeID)
     );

 create table room_rate (
     room_rateID     int auto_increment not null primary key,
     room_typeID     int not null,
     season_type     varchar(50) not null,
     monRate         double not null,
     tuesRate       double not null,
     wedRate     double not null,
     thuRate     double not null,
     friRate     double not null,
     satRate     double not null,
     sunRate     double not null,
     adult       int,
     children    int,
     foreign key(room_typeID)references room_type(room_typeID)
     );


  create table room_type (
         room_typeID    int auto_increment not null primary key,
     room_type   varchar(50) not null,
     room_type_des  varchar(200)
     );

   create table room (
       room_id          int unique primary key auto_increment not null,
       room_number      int unique not null,
       room_typeID      int not null,
       room_adultcapacity    int not null,
       room_childcapacity    int not null,
       room_img         varchar(100),
       room_status      int(1),
       foreign key(room_typeID)references room_type(room_typeID)
        );

  create table reservation ( 
      reserve_code          varchar(20) primary key unique not null,       
      guest_id              int not null,
      foreign key(guest_id)references guest(guest_id),
      room_id          int,
      foreign key(room_id)references room(room_id),
      reserve_date_start         date,
      reserve_date_end          date,
      reserve_status      int(1)
     );
```

here is the records

```
INSERT INTO `reservation` (`reserve_code`, `guest_id`, `room_id`, `reserve_date_start`, `reserve_date_end`, `reserve_status`) VALUES
    ('p28ypfgWO3Ijfn3eO5Vk', 18, NULL, 2, '2018-06-18', '2018-06-22', 1),
    ('67Bs8MKTOjZ2eJ9fxMPF', 18, NULL, 3, '2018-06-24', '2018-06-29', 1);


INSERT INTO `room` (`room_id`, `room_number`, `room_typeID`, `room_adultcapacity`, `room_childcapacity`, `room_img`, `room_status`) VALUES
    (2, 102, 2, 2, 2, '../image-upload/room7.jpg', 1),
      (3, 103, 2, 2, 2, '../image-upload/room8.jpg', 1),
    (4, 104, 3, 2, 2, '../image-upload/room9.jpg', NULL),
    (5, 105, 3, 2, 1, '../image-upload/room10.jpg', NULL);
```

this is the check in and check out dates from the form check availability

```
desire-check-in-dates date("2018-06-17")
desire-check-out-dates date("2018-06-23")
```

here is my query

```
    "select distinct room_type.room_type, room_type.room_typeID, room_type.room_type_des, room.room_id, room.room_number, room.room_typeID, room.room_adultcapacity, room.room_childcapacity, room.room_img, room.room_status
                     from room 
left outer  join room_type on room.room_typeID = room_type.room_typeID 
left outer join room_rate_default on room_type.room_typeID = room_rate_default.room_typeID
left outer join room_rate on room_type.room_typeID = room_rate.room_typeID
                     where room.room_id not in ('select room_id from reservation where date('2018-06-17') between 
               reserve_date_start and reserve_date_end or date('2018-06-23') between 
               reserve_date_start and reserve_date_end or date('2018-06-17') < 
               reserve_date_start and date('2018-06-23') > reserve_date_end') or room.room_status is null";
```

i don't know what is the error of my query..
 in this query i want to display the room_id 3, 4 and 5 but my query is not working..

Comment: question can not be read

Comment: Left outer join is not valid MySQL syntax...

Comment: @LelioFaieta no,`left outer join` is equal to `left join`

Comment: not in (' - is incorrect there should not be a quote here. BTW why is your query in "

Comment: ahh ok i try to change it into a double quote sir Salmon

Comment: IF this is a pure mysql question It shouldn't be quoted at all (neither should reserve_date_end' )

Answer (score 0):

This query is working now
 This is the answer of my question
 Thank u sir @P.Salmon for the help

```
select distinct room_type.room_type, room_type.room_typeID, room_type.room_type_des, room.room_id, room.room_number, room.room_typeID, room.room_adultcapacity, room.room_childcapacity, room.room_img, room.room_status
                     from room left outer  join room_type on room.room_typeID = room_type.room_typeID left outer join room_rate_default on room_type.room_typeID = room_rate_default.room_typeID
                     left outer join room_rate on room_type.room_typeID = room_rate.room_typeID
                     where room.room_id not in (select room_id from reservation where date('2018-06-17') between 
                     reserve_date_start and reserve_date_end or date('2018-06-23') between 
                     reserve_date_start and reserve_date_end or date('2018-06-17') < 
                     reserve_date_start and date('2018-06-23') > reserve_date_end) or room.room_status is null
```

Comment: Welcome on the SO! I suggest to give more answer than a code snippet, that makes your answer much better.